# Indenting text on html select tag

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a select tag which I am trying to give some style.

```
<select class="points-selection"
        ng-options="line as line.pick for line in slip.lines">
</select>
```

then I have this

```
  .points-selection {
    background-color: get-color(nieve);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: get-space(xxx-small);
    color: get-color(night);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: get-space(xxx-small) + 1.5;
    padding: get-space(xxx-small);
    text-indent: 32.5%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

I have that `text-indent` prop set to 32.5%.

In chrome is doing this

[image]

which is exactly what I need.

But I have this on Firefox

[image]

clearly the text is not centered in Firefox, that's my issue so far.

so what should I do to fix it ?

Comment: Why don't you use `text-align:center` rather than `text-indent`?

Comment: @IrvinLim that doesn't have any effect on select tag. That's why

Comment: aren't those being output in <option> elements? put the style on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try normalizing the css for every browser

```
*{
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
 }
```

or go to this link [Normalize.css in GitHub](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)